# ESM apps are disabled, even though they are enabled

Tags: esm

The image explains it all, I've activated esm-apps, although it doesn't seem like they're activated. On pro status it says they're on, but when I'm logging to my PC it clearly says they're disabled.

[image]

Comment: If you run `sudo pro status` does it actually show `enabled` or `disabled`?

Comment: it shows enabled

Comment: if i'm doing fresh install when attaching my code during it, it doesn't work either

Comment: From what I can see it is the `update-notifier` that is not setting the ESM Apps message to enabled even though they are.  If you cat the file `/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available` you will see that message about it being disabled.  I am trying to look further into if you can force the `update-notifier` to check that and change it.

Comment: I think I have an answer for you.  Let me write one up.

Answer (score 0):

The message that you are seeing is because the `update-notifier` for some reason is not updating the `/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available` file with the proper information that the esm-apps are enabled.

To get it to show that the apps are enabled you can do it as a 3 step process.

1. Disable the `esm-app` by running `sudo pro disable esm-apps`
2. Remove the `updates-available` file by running `sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available`
3. Re-enable the `esm-apps` by running `sudo pro enable esm-apps` and now it should say enabled when you log back in.

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ssh intrepid
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.2.0-37-generic x86_64)

  System information as of Fri Dec  1 10:01:23 PM MST 2023

  System load:  0.49                Processes:              250
  Usage of /:   77.0% of 454.44GB   Users logged in:        0
  Memory usage: 5%                  IPv4 address for bond0: 10.0.0.220
  Swap usage:   0%                  IPv4 address for tun0:  10.8.0.1

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

You have new mail.
Last login: Fri Dec  1 22:00:56 2023 from 10.0.0.100

terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo pro disable esm-apps
Updating package lists
terrance@Intrepid:~$ exit

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ssh intrepid
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.2.0-37-generic x86_64)

  System information as of Fri Dec  1 10:07:32 PM MST 2023

  System load:  0.42                Processes:              246
  Usage of /:   77.0% of 454.44GB   Users logged in:        0
  Memory usage: 5%                  IPv4 address for bond0: 10.0.0.220
  Swap usage:   0%                  IPv4 address for tun0:  10.8.0.1

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

You have new mail.
Last login: Fri Dec  1 22:01:24 2023 from 10.0.0.100
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo pro status
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS       DESCRIPTION
anbox-cloud      yes       disabled     Scalable Android in the cloud
esm-apps         yes       disabled     Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications

terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available

terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease           
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease . . . . . .                     


terrance@Intrepid:~$ cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

56 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm

terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo pro enable esm-apps
One moment, checking your subscription first
Updating Ubuntu Pro: ESM Apps package lists
Ubuntu Pro: ESM Apps enabled

terrance@Intrepid:~$ cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.
```